# .NET Dynamic Decision to Call Similar Classes?

Tags: dynamic, reflection

C# on .NET 4.5:

```
 public Interface IMyInterface
    {
    public string DoSomething( string input1 )
    }

    public MyClass1 : IMyInterface
    {
    public string DoSomething( string input1 )
    {
    return "1";
    }
    }

    public MyClass2 : IMyInterface
    {
    public string DoSomething( string input1 )
    {
    return "2";
    }
    }
```

At runtime, I want to detect the hosting environment, set some kind of "global", and then based on the global always instance and use MyClass1 or MyClass2. I do not want to have a single "MyClass" and then do lots of case logic inside it to detect the environment.

What is a good pattern or practice to do that? Is this actually a good place for Dynamics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to use Factory. Create a method in Factory class to return MyClass object. Keep the return type of the method as `IMyInterface`. Within the method, you can execute your hosting logic and depending upon the output of hosting logic, instantiate proper class and return the reference to the object.